# Play flv file on FMS

Tags: apache-flex, video, playback, flash-media-server

I have per-recorded .flv file, Now I want to play this video on Flash Media Server.I created a folder name "sampleApplication" in my directory C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flash Media Server 3\applications\ directory. Now I write code to make connection

```
    netConnection.connect("rtmpt://localhost:1935/sampleApplication");
    netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, checkConnection);
```

In checkConnection listener I check that my connection is perfectly working and then i code to play the video

```
   netStream = new NetStream(netConnection);
   vid = new Video(300, 300);
   vid.attachNetStream(netStream);
   videoPlayer.addChild(vid);
   netStream.play("sample");
```

video is not going to be played...
what is problem..Urgent help required?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put your **sample.flv** to `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flash Media Server 3\sampleApplication\streams\_definst_\` folder

Comment: Great...it works thanks a lot davydick..I put my video in steam/definst_ folder and i got it working but i got one exception  Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: flash.net.NetStream was unable to invoke callback onMetaData. error=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property onMetaData not found on flash.net.NetStream and there is no default value.